# How do we allocate memory for returning a char**

Tags: c, pointers, return, malloc, return-value

I have the method...

`char** getStrings();` which will return a pointer to char pointers.

is it possible to do ..

```
char** allStrings = getStrings()?
```

or must I do something like...

```
char** alStrings = malloc(sizeof(char*) * numberOfStrings);
allStrings = getStrings()
//where numberOfStrings is some int.
```

Comment: Unless you like hunting memory leaks, avoid the latter entirely.

Comment: The last one is odd -- but harmless until the typo in the variable names is fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first one is obviously correct.
The second one, after fixing the typo, is equal to the first one plus a memory leak.

Please also refer to the functions contract for accessing all those strings, and for deallocation.

You probably get a `NULL`-terminated array of `0`-terminated strings, but deallocation might be trickier.

Likely deallocation choices:

- Static data, trap for multithreading/recursion/multi-call trap, no explicit deallocation needed nor permissible.
- All in one block, only free the main pointer.
- Each component must be freed separately.

Answer (score 1):

If `getStrings()` does the allocation for you, then of course `char **allStrings = getStrings()` is fine.